# Differentiation of an infinite series of functions

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives, lebesgue-measure

**I want to show:**

If

$$f(x) :=\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} g_n(x)$$

where the series is convergent for every $x \in [a,b]$ and $g_n(x)$ is a nondecreasing function on $[a,b]$ for each $n$ ; then

$$f'(x) = \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} g_n'(x)$$ almost everywhere.

**Thoughts:**

Since $g_n$'s are nondecreasing, $f$ is monoton and by Lebesgue's related theorem $f$ is differentiable a.e. on $[a,b]$.  The nondecreasing property is crucial, without that I can state counter examples.

Statement obviously true for finite case. However I couldnt pass to the limit. I am totally stuck here. Could you please help me on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *Fubini's theorem on differentiation*.

**Hint:** Let $S_n(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n g_i(x)$. Except on a null set, we have 
$$
S'_{n-1}(x) \leq S'_n(x) \leq f'(x)
$$ 
which implies that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} S'_n(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty g'_n(x)$ converges almost everywhere. Now try to construct a subsequence $S'_{n_k}(x)$ converging to $f'(x)$, and it's done.

You may need to use monotonicity multiple times in the proof.

Comment: Okay, i did work out in a similar way. I see the $S_{n-1}'(x) \leq S_{n}'(x)$ part, but i can't see $S_{n}'(x) \leq f'(x)$

Comment: @iamvegan $f(x) - S_n(x) = \sum_{k = n+1}^\infty f_k(x)$, which is increasing and thus $f'(x) - S_n'(x) \geq 0$.

Comment: That resolves my problems, thank you for your help.